# JSON Array to CSV via FasterCSV

Tags: json, ruby, csv, parsing, fastercsv

I have a JSON array in the following format.

```
[{"Name":"Ann","Gender":"Female","Age":"20"},{"Name":"John","Gender":"Male","Age":"22"}]
```

I want to convert this into following CSV format without printing the "Key" and also i want it to print only the `Name` value and `Age` value.
for e.g.
Ann,20
John,22

I have tried with following code.

```
#!//usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require 'fastercsv'
require 'json'

csv_string = FasterCSV.generate({}) do |csv|
   JSON.parse(File.open("test").read).each do |hash|
    csv << hash
  end
end

puts csv_string
```

`test` contains the json array which i'm try to parse.

Comment: What happened with `"Gender"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON format is invalid. Valid json format is:

```
[{"Name":"Ann","Gender":"Female","Age":"20"},{"Name":"John","Gender":"Male","Age":"22"}]
```

Try this:

```
require "rubygems"
require 'fastercsv'
require 'json'

csv_string = FasterCSV.generate({}) do |csv|
  JSON.parse(File.open("test").read).each do |hash|
    csv << [hash["Name"], hash["Age"]]
  end
end

puts csv_string
```